# how to extends a module in typescript

Tags: typescript

I'm still new to typescript, so any direction would be appreciated. Thanks!

file A:

```
   module SoundManager {
    export class SoundManager {

    }

    export function init($s: string):void {

    } }
```

file B:

```
module SoundM {
    class SoundM extends SoundManager {
    }

    export function init($s:string): void {
        super.init($s);
    }
}
```

this will return the error:

> Error   TS2507  Type 'typeof SoundManager' is not a constructor function type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you speak of is demonstrated below:

[image]

It is actually because you are using the `SoundManager` *namespace* and not `class`. Fix:

```
module SoundManager {
    export class SoundManager {

    }

    export function init($s: string): void {

    }
}

module SoundM {
    class SoundM extends SoundManager.SoundManager {
    }
}
```

That said. Please look at using modules : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/project/modules.html